# Why do I get many NA's in a "for" loop that simulates Poisson random variables

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, na, poisson

I keep getting error messages saying that I am creating hundreds of `NA`'s in my `for` loop. Where do those `NA` come from? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
drip <- function(rate = 1, minutes = 120) {
  count <- 0
  for(i in 1:(minutes)) {
    count <- count + rpois(1, rate)
    rate <- rate * runif(1, 0, 5)
  }
  count
}
drip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get integer overflow. Try

```
set.seed(0)
rpois(1, 1e+8)
#[1] 100012629
rpois(1, 1e+9)
#[1] 999989683
rpois(1, 1e+10)
#[1] NA
#Warning message:
#In rpois(1, 1e+10) : NAs produced
```

As soon as `lambda` is too large, 32-bit representation of integer is insufficient and `NA` is returned. (Recall that Poisson random variables are integers).

Your loop has a dynamic growth on `rate` (`lambda`), which can eventually become too big. Running your function with a smaller `minutes`, say `10`, is fine.

By contrast, `ppois` and `dpois` which produce double-precision floating point numbers are fine with large `lambda`.

```
dpois(1e+8, 1e+8)
#[1] 3.989423e-05
dpois(1e+9, 1e+9)
#[1] 1.261566e-05
dpois(1e+10, 1e+10)
#[1] 3.989423e-06
dpois(1e+11, 1e+11)
#[1] 1.261566e-06

ppois(1e+8, 1e+8)
#[1] 0.5000266
ppois(1e+9, 1e+9)
#[1] 0.5000084
ppois(1e+10, 1e+10)
#[1] 0.5000027
ppois(1e+11, 1e+11)
#[1] 0.5000008
```

---

> With each passing minute, the rate parameter increases by `x%`, where `x` is a random value from the uniform distribution on the interval `[0, 5]`.

The `rate` increases by `x%` not `x`. So you should use

```
rate <- rate * (1 + runif(1, 0, 5) / 100)
```